# Read a geojson file with mixed geometries geojsonio::geojson_read

Tags: r, shiny, geojson, geojsonio

I am trying to create a chorpleth of Belgium in shiny (R) using [this geojson file (github view)](https://github.com/RobinVdE/GeoJsonView/blob/master/belgium_municipalities.json). I am following [the tutorial of rstudio](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/choropleths.html) to get the basics right. While doing this I encountered the following error while trying to use the `geojsonio::geojson_read()` function.

```
Error: Multiple incompatible geometries: wkbPolygon: 586; wkbGeometryCollection: 3
```

After some debugging I found that, indeed there are 3 GeometryCollections. However these collections are municipalities that have enclaves (multiple polygons for one municipality). One of which it the famous border craziness of [Baarle Hertog/Baarle-Nassau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baarle-Hertog). So both wkbPloygons and wkbGeometryCollection should be inside the same layer for plotting.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: How do you produce your GeoJSON? Normally, it should contains MultiPolygon. GeometryCollection are not needed to manage enclaves. I have generated GeoJSON from http://www.atlas-belgique.be/cms2/index.php?page=cartodata_fr and the output is Multipolygon only https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/ab994f805627c4c121615455ded949d7 (GeoJSON not simplified and with different attributes)

Comment: Can you try to install dev version  of `geojsonio` like `remotes::install_github("ropensci/geojsonio")`. it works for me.

Comment: `sf <- sf::st_read(geojson_url); sf <- geojsonsf::geojson_sf(geojson_url)` both also work for reading GeoJSON, and both give you an `sf` object